# How to register and login user with phone number using OTP only Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to register and login user with OTP alone. User is going to verify his phone number and it will log him in directly.

I couldnt find any adequate solution for Woocommerce login process and tried to disable email for wordpress but it didnt help me. Could you please guide me through how can i achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.

```
// This will suppress empty email errors when submitting the user form

   add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'my_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );

function my_user_profile_update_errors($errors, $update, $user) {

    $errors->remove('empty_email');

}



// This will remove javascript required validation for email input

// It will also remove the '(required)' text in the label

// Works for new user, user profile and edit user forms

add_action('user_new_form', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);

add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);

add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_new_form', 10, 1);

function my_user_new_form($form_type) {

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery('#email').closest('tr').removeClass('form-required').find('.description').remove();

        // Uncheck send new user email option by default

        <?php if (isset($form_type) && $form_type === 'add-new-user') : ?>

            jQuery('#send_user_notification').removeAttr('checked');

        <?php endif; ?>

    </script>

    <?php

}
```

I was trying to disable email registration for Wordpress and Woocommerce and register only with phone number. But it didn't work.